# Image not displaying in material-ui CardMedia element

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I've created a simplified version of an issue I am having in my application.

I have a card component (represented here by `MyCardComponent`) which I want to pass a string prop into with the location of an image file and have that rendered in a `CardMedia` element on a material-ui  `Card`

*However the image doesn't appear, how do I get it to render* ? . See issue re-created in CodeSandbox

[image: Edit image-on-card]

**MyCardComponent.js**

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import "./styles.css";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { Card, CardMedia, CardContent } from "@material-ui/core";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  cardRootStyle: {
    minHeight: 300,
    maxHeight: 300
  },
  cardMediaStyle: {
    minHeight: 100,
    maxHeight: 100
  }
}));
export default function MyCardComponent(props) {
  const styles = useStyles();
  return (
    <>
      <Card
        classes={{
          root: styles.cardRootStyle
        }}
      >
        <CardContent>
          <CardMedia image={props.imagePath} />
        </CardContent>
      </Card>
    </>
  );
}

MyCardComponent.propTypes = {
  imagePath: PropTypes.string
};
```

I call `MyCardComponent` like this

```
<MyCardComponent imagePath='/static/sampleimages/cocacola.png'/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found two issues:

1. Problem with image path.
2. You forgot use `paddingTop`. Read [the docs](https://material-ui.com/components/cards/#complex-interaction).

[Here an example](https://codesandbox.io/s/image-on-card-ke377?file=/src/MyCardComponent.js).

Comment: Thanks for your example. I can now see that I should have had the image within the public directory of my app and not in its own static directory at that level. All working now 

Answer (score 1):

First try to import your image with

```
import cocacola from 'whereveryourimageis/cocacola.png'
```

Then use it like this

```
imagePath={cocacola}
```

And now it's there!

But won't show up, because apparently your .MuiCardMedia-root has height = 0, so you should deal with that too